# Row count in Hbase where a column has certain value

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am using hbase to store my data in hdfs, I have a column family with user_details in my table where I am storing user values like-

```
userdetails-> userid ->"ui011"
userdetails-> userName->"John"
userdetails-> emailid->"john@xyz.com"
```

Now is it possible to count the rows which have particular value in username and email id, both through java and hbase shell. I am kind of new to hbase and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Hbase coprocessor AggregationClient . [AggregationClient docs](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/coprocessor/AggregationClient.html)

Example usage:  [row-count-hbase-aggregation-example](http://michaelmorello.blogspot.com/2012/01/row-count-hbase-aggregation-example.html)